# How can I do maps involving string fields in rethinkdb?

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I want to modify the timestamps of everything in my table. It seems like I should be able to use `for_each` but I'm not sure how.

Based on the [documentation](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/#for_each), I think my function should return a write object. But I'm having trouble doing things involving strings. Here is a very simple example:

```
r.expr([{'time':"2014"}]).map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['time'],'%Y'))
```

This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: must be string, not GetField
```

Interestingly, the following works:

```
map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y'), 
    r.expr([{'time':"2014"}])
     .map(lambda x: x['time'])
     .run(conn))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strptime` is a python method and not a ReQL one, so you cannot send it to the server.

When you call `run` on your query, The driver will save the output of the lambda function when called with a ReQL object.When it will hit `datetime.strptime(x['time'],'%Y'))` you will get an error, because you call `datetime.strptime` with a non-valid argument.

If you are interested in knowing a little more, you can take a look at: http://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/lambda-functions/

You probably want to store the year as a number. That way, the query you are looking for I think is

```
r.expr([{'time':2014}]).map(lambda x: r.time(x['time'], 1, 1, '+00:00')
```

If you want to keep a string, you can do

```
r.expr([{'time':2014}]).map(lambda x: r.time(x['time'].coerce_to("NUMBER"), 1, 1, '+00:00')
```